# Which are the best source to learn Animation from Scratch for Android Application Development.

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-activity

Can anybody please suggest me a source or book or link to learn Animation for Android Application Development from Scratch.

Comment: [Google](http://www.google.com)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen the [**Adding Animations**](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/index.html) tutorial & example ? Here they have shown different techniques to achieve some nice animated visual effects.